# Installing multiple os after installing windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, debian, multi-boot, windows-8

I have made a **fresh** windows **8** installation awhile ago. And, now want to install 3 more OS:

1. Windows **7** - for using VS 2010.
2. Windows **7** - for general usage.
3. *Debian 6* - for programming, web development etc. [*please don't convince me this isn't needed* :D]

I have a 750GB hard disk that is partitioned this way as of now:

[image]

*note*: `DEBAIN` partition will become `ext4` format while installing debian.

Anyway, now that you understand my situation, I would like to know how I would go about achieving what I want with out losing my gold.

If windows 8 was out of question, I'd happily use [`easybcd`](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) after installing `debian (with grub in its own partition) > windows 7 #2 > windows 7 #1` from `windows 7 #1`.

But, I am not sure I can use that now. Because you know, windows 8 introduced a new boot manager and blah.. blah..

So, How would I go about installing 2 windows 7s and a debian in my system?

It would be awesome if someone could post an answer or a link that will walk me through the process.

Answer (score 1):

You would basically just install each os on their respective partitions (making sure you do not install on or format the "gold" partition) then use EasyBCD to create those boot menu items. I dual booted my Windows 8 pc this way and it worked for me. Also, in Windows 8 you will want to uncheck **Turn on fast startup** in *Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\System Settings*.

Comment: I didn't know easybcd was windows 8 ready. Also, thanks for the tip about fast startup. Will get back to you (hopefully :D) again with my status once I install these. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't officially support Windows 8, but it works just fine with it.